# Decompressing LZW image data in TIF file - image data doesn't start with clear code

Tags: c#, compression, tiff, lzw

I'm writing a C# library to interpret and display images from TIF files, where the image data strips are compressed using LZW compression.  I'm testing it with a set of 21 TIF files which were produced by another application, which I've got no control over.

I've read somewhere that the image data should start with the clear code, but it's not in the Adobe TIFF6 spec and I can't find the source of that now.

In 14 of the test files, the image data starts with the LZW Clear code value of 256 (the first bytes in the image data are 0x8000, so the first 9 bits of 1000 0000 0000 0000 are 1 0000 0000 = 256 decimal).  I can decompress and display these no problem.

However in 7 of the files, the first two bytes of the LZW compressed data are either 0x06FA, 0x0712 or 0x097A.  Obviously these aren't the clear code which would trigger me to initialize my LZW string table.  Even when the LZW string table is initialized with the initial 256 values, I'm very quickly encountering codes in the LZW compressed data which don't have a corresponding entry in the string table, causing an error.

```
0x06FA = 0000 0110 1111 1010 first 9 bits = 0 0000 1101 = 0x0D = 13 decimal
0x0712 = 0000 0111 0001 0010 first 9 bits = 0 0000 1110 = 0x0E = 14 decimal
0x097A = 0000 1001 0111 1010 first 9 bits = 0 0001 0010 = 0x12 = 18 decimal
```

Do these values have some special meaning that I haven't discovered yet?  Should they be treated as regular codes into the string table?  If so, why am I subsequently running into codes which haven't yet got an entry in the string table? Or do the 7 files I'm having trouble with not conform to the spec? They display fine in IrfanView so I assume they do conform.

Here's my decompression code, which I've kept as close to the algorithm in the TIFF6 spec as possible.

```
        public byte[] DecompressToBytes()
        {
            List<byte> decompressed = new List<byte>();
            int oldCode = 0;
            int code = 0;
            string entry;

            // Just in case the first code we encounter isn't the clearcode.
            initializeDictionary();

            // getNextCode decides whether to read a 9, 10, 11 or 12 bit value
            // based on size of string table Dictionary.
            while(((code = getNextCode()) != EndOfInformation))     // EndOfInformation = 257
            {
                if(code == ClearCode)                               // ClearCode = 256
                {
                    initializeDictionary();
                    code = getNextCode();
                    if(code == EndOfInformation)
                        break;
                    entry = Dictionary[code];
                    // convert string (eg "0A0B0C") to bytes and add to output.
                    addBytes(decompressed, entry);                  
                    oldCode = code;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(Dictionary.ContainsKey(code))
                    {
                        entry = Dictionary[code];
                        addBytes(decompressed, entry);
                        Dictionary.Add(Dictionary.Count, stringFromCode(oldCode) + stringFromCode(code).Substring(0, 2));
                        oldCode = code;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        entry = stringFromCode(oldCode) + stringFromCode(oldCode).Substring(0, 2);
                        addBytes(decompressed, entry);
                        Dictionary.Add(Dictionary.Count, entry);
                        oldCode = code;
                    }
                }
            }
            return decompressed.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: could that be starts of multipage chunks inside the image descriptor? look how others do it: https://github.com/piksels-and-lines-orchestra/gimp/blob/7f9a9ce331d36b8d662ac2f6c3a1125ecc3397a5/plug-ins/common/file-tiff-load.c#L754

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface You might be on to something. The files I can display successfully all have RowsPerStrip == ImageLength, i.e. the whole image is in a single strip. The ones I'm having a problem with have RowsPerStrip < ImageLength. I need to check again how I'm handling multiple strips.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this off, I had misunderstood the spec.  The files that were causing me a problem had the image data in multiple strips.  What I thought was the start of the image data was actually the start of the offsets to the individual strips.